# Is there a way to add a HeaderField to the Shipping and Billing form fields in silvershop-Core

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to add a HeaderField:: to visually split up the billing and shipping form fields generated in SilverShop-Core.

I have tried to add the Headerfield in the Checkout.php file as well as each of the ShippingAddress.php and BillingAddress.php files. The closest I have managed to get so far is to add it in the Address.php file (located in the Model folder). But I need some help with writing the code to specify that, if the form fields are for Billing then the heading field should show Billing address.The same process for shipping. I suspect I need an If Else statement but I don't know where or how to write this.

I have added a field HeaderField in the function beforeUpdateCMSFields as well as getFrontEndFields.

...

```
class Address extends DataObject 
{
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $self = $this;

    $this->beforeUpdateCMSFields(
        function (FieldList $fields) use ($self) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab(
                'Root.Main',
                $self->getCountryField(),
                'State'
            );
            $fields->addFieldToTab(
                'Root.Main',
                $self->HeaderField(),
                'Address'
            );


            $fields->removeByName('MemberID');
        }
    );

    return parent::getCMSFields();
}

public function getFrontEndFields($params = null)
{
    $fields = new FieldList(
        HeaderField::create('Header', $this->fieldLabel('Address'))->addExtraClass('BubblesFormSections'),
        $this->getCountryField(),
        $addressfield = TextField::create('Address', $this->fieldLabel('Address')),
        $address2field =
            TextField::create('AddressLine2', $this->fieldLabel('AddressLine2')),
        $cityfield = TextField::create('City', $this->fieldLabel('City')),
        $statefield = TextField::create('State', $this->fieldLabel('State')),
        $postcodefield = TextField::create('PostalCode', $this->fieldLabel('PostalCode')),
        $phonefield = TextField::create('Phone', $this->fieldLabel('Phone'))
    );
    if (!empty($params['addfielddescriptions'])) {
        $addressfield->setDescription(
            _t(__CLASS__ . '.AddressHint', 'street / thoroughfare number, name, and type or P.O. Box')
        );
        $address2field->setDescription(
            _t(__CLASS__ . '.AddressLine2Hint', 'premises, building, apartment, unit, floor')
        );
        $cityfield->setDescription(_t(__CLASS__ . '.CityHint', 'or suburb, county, district'));
        $statefield->setDescription(_t(__CLASS__ . '.StateHint', 'or province, territory, island'));
    }

    $this->extend('updateFormFields', $fields);
    return $fields;
}
```

...

On the checkout page I would like to see a heading identifying that some form fields are for Billing and the other form fields are for shipping.

Comment: I have managed to add  HeaderField to the CustomerDetails file located under "Checkout ->Component" folders. I attempted to add a headerfield for billing but it's not showing and no error messages. Any suggestions for adding a headerfield?


    class BillingAddress extends Address
    {
    private static $table_name = 'SilverShop_BillingAddress';
  
  public function getFrontEndFields()
    {
        $fields = new FieldList(
   HeaderField::create('Header', 'Billing address')->addExtraClass('BubblesFormSections')
            
        );
        
        return $fields;
    }

Comment: I have also managed to add the headerfield to the Membership file successfully.

Comment: Made some changes to Billing Address and managed to get the HeaderField to show but not the associated billing form fields are missing.

public function getFormFields($fields)
    {
        $fields = FieldList::create(
  HeaderField::create('Header', 'Billing address')->addExtraClass('BubblesFormSections')
        );

        return $fields;
    }